# accessing university building information google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Which google maps api library would I use to access the university campus information displayed at the bottom when clicking anywhere on campus?

Link to university campus map: https://www.google.com/maps/@30.2779322,-97.7391044,971a,20y,41.44t/data=!3m1!1e3

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is quite broad and for the moment you don't show anything that you may have tried before asking this question. It is typically appreciated if you don't just ask people try write code for you but show your own efforts, problems that you encountered, things that you need help with.

Comment: I've revised my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature in any of the Google Maps API. You can have just the images at the bottom using [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro) or using  [Street View Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview?hl=en)

You can get places detail using [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details)

Comment: Thank you so much Verma!